# Getting error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in file

Tags: laravel, string-comparison

I am trying to get the 'occupation' atrribute from the 'preferences(id,occupation,marital_status,City)' table by id and compare the attribute 'occupation' to another table called 'user_more_infos(id,age,occupation,marital_status,City)'. I want to show the id of the people who have the same occupation in the user_more_infos table.

```
public function match(){

$id= Auth::id();

$find=DB::table('preferences')->where('id','like',$id)->select('occupation')->get();

$occupation=DB::table('user_more_infos')->where('occupation','like',$find)->select('id')->get();
return $occupation;
}
```

Comment: Please, no images. Copy and paste your code here. Highlight and click `{}` to get nice formatting.

Comment: Nice, looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should write your code:

```
public function match()
{
    $id = Auth::id();
    $find = DB::table('preferences')
            ->where('id','like',$id)
            ->select('occupation')
            ->first();
            
    $occupation = DB::table('user_more_infos')
            ->where('occupation','like',$find->occupation)
            ->select('id')
            ->get();
            
    return $occupation;
}
```

However, you need not have created a different table for your required solution. you can use an inner join to find similar values from a single table itself.
You can learn how to use that here, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins

Let me know if the snippet above works for you.

Comment: you are most welcome. do set this as answer as right answer so that others also will find the solution if any

Comment: As a sidenote: `->select('occupation')->first()->occupation` can be simplified as `->value('occupation')`